# Magento 2 : how to add additional information in rest API response?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, magento2.2.3

I have one custom table **'vendor_info'** with 5 fields and I want to add this table data along with this API http://www.hostname.com/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using 2 ways

1. [Search Criteria join processors](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/searching-with-repositories.html)
2. Adding extension attributes , you can write after plugin **get** and **getList** methods to get value corresponding value of vendor_info for the products and set extension attribute to them

You can get detail reference from these links  [Reference](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html) 1 [Reference 2](https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/adding-custom-attribute-to-api-response-in-magento-2/)